# how to mix and/or operators in an if-else in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I've been trying to find example(s) but getting nowhere.

I'm trying to write this expression (not so complex) as a if-else statement in bash.

```
if (expr1 and (expr2 or expr3)) then
  do-something
fi
```

Any ideas how it can be done? thanks

Comment: You can use `if [ expr1 ] && [ expr2 -o expr3 ]`, but I am not sure if it is the best way. It works, though: `[ "$a" -eq 1 ] && [ "$b" -eq 3 -o "$c" -eq 2 ] && echo "yes"`

Comment: `a and (b or c)` is same as `b or c and a`

Comment: see chapter 7.2.4 here: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way of expressing it would be:

```
if [ expr1 ] && [[ expr2 || expr3 ]]; then
   # do something
fi
```

instead of using the test command and making use of the following form:

```
  EXPR1 -o EXPR2 True if either expr1 OR expr2 is true.
```

From `help [[`:

```
  EXPR1 || EXPR2    True if either EXPR1 or EXPR2 is true; else false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
if [ expr1 ] && ([ expr2 ] || [ expr3 ]); then
  #do something
else
   #do something else
fi
```

there’s a neat trick you can use to quickly test a condition:

```
[ expr1 ] && ([ expr2 ] || [ expr3 ]) && echo "something" || echo "something else"
```

Comment: ad the `cond && ifyes || ifno` - it is nice, but must be beware, because when the `ifyes` failed you will end with `ifno` anyway...